# Can we pass Java Object as report parameter to BIRT Report

Tags: java, birt

I have a report which calls a Procedure and then create DataSet from temp table.
Now what we want is instead of calling procedure we want to call Procedure from our `java` project and create an `java` Object of the result set and pass that `java` object as a parameter to `BIRT`.

Now the problem which i am facing is will `BIRT` supports only primitive types as parameter type not `JAVA` Object, So is there any way to pass `Java` Object as a report parameter to `BIRT`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *AppContext* object to pass anything to the report. This is a Map (String->Object). You can put your object into this map from the Java side before starting the RunTask or RunAndRenderTask, for example

```
runAndRenderTask.getAppContext().put("myKey", myObject);
```

Inside the BIRT report, you can access the AppContext from Javascript with reportContext.getAppContext(), for example

```
var myObject = reportContext.getAppContext().get("myKey");
```

For more information, see the BIRT documentation, e.g. http://developer.actuate.com/be/documentation/ihub3/help/adg/adg62/index.html#page/ADG/ScriptingWithJavaScript.1.05.html#ww253653 for details

BTW you can also use the AppContext to return information from the BIRT report to your application by writing to it from the Javascript side.

Please note that objects passed by the AppContext must be serializable.

Comment: thanks hvb, but my problem is we are not using reports engine apis , we are using webviewer for our reports. It is still possible in any way to pass an object as a report parameter.

Comment: If everything is running in the same Java process, yes: You could store your object into a global cache (say, singleton Map<String,Object>) under a unique (generated) name and just pass the name to your report. Then inside BIRT, you can access the singleton map from Javascript (hint: look examples of using Java objects from BIRT javascript) to access the object by its name.

Comment: Thanks a lot hvb your help has saved my day! :)